# Do I need to define a function before it can be execute if the call to the function is in the same module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following javascript:

```
var User;
(function (User) {
    (function (AccessControls) {
        User.AccessControls.loginFormSubmit();
        function loginFormSubmit() {
            $('#article').on('submit', '#loginForm form', function () {
                var $form = $(this);
                if(!$form.valid()) {
                    return false;
                }
                var myData = $form.serialize();
                var myUrl = $form.attr("action");
                return false;
            });
        }
        AccessControls.loginFormSubmit = loginFormSubmit;
    })(User.AccessControls || (User.AccessControls = {}));
    var AccessControls = User.AccessControls;
})(User || (User = {}));
//@ sourceMappingURL=loginFormSubmit.js.map
```

The exact error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loginFormSubmit'
```

Can anyone explain why I would get this error?

Here's my typescript code if that helps:

```
module User {

    export module AccessControls {

        loginFormSubmit();

        export function loginFormSubmit() {

            $('#article').on('submit', '#loginForm form', function () {
                var $form = $(this);

                // if there are validation errors do not continue.
                if (!$form.valid()) {
                    return false;
                }

                // get the form data
                var myData = $form.serialize();

                // get the url to post to from the form's action attribute.
                var myUrl = $form.attr("action");

                // execute the post
                //$.ajax({
                //    url: myUrl,
                //    data: myData
                //success: function(data) {
                //    // on success, write the returned article content into the article element
                //    $('#article').html(data);
                //}
                return false;
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: no, the browser reads all javascript code before executing. can you post more details for this issue

Comment: Is the message in the typescript compiler thing or in the Javascript console?

Comment: I posted the exact code. I am getting it in the Google Chrome developer tools. Hope showing the js code helps.

Comment: Does it need also `User.` at this line: ´AccessControls.loginFormSubmit = loginFormSubmit;`

Comment: Have you tried calling `loginFormSubmit()` after having defined it in the `AccessControls` Module ?

Comment: It works now as I just call loginFormSubmit. I can mark as accepted if Chris wants to add as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it need also `User.` at the following line?

```
AccessControls.loginFormSubmit = loginFormSubmit;
```